# sort order if empty then products are not displayed

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have created custom post types and custom taxonomy. In the taxonomy i have a field for sort order. if sort order is left empty then the products category is not displayed. Code related to sort order is this.

**Code for sort order**

```
<tr class="form-field">
   <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_sort_order"><?php _e('Product Sort Order'); ?></label></th>
   <td>
        <input id="banner-url" name="term_meta[sort_order]" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['sort_order'] ? $term_meta['sort_order'] : ''; ?>" />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('&nbsp;'); ?></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Function for calling**

```
 $term = get_term($product, 'product-cat',array( 'parent' => 0,'hide_empty'=> true ));
        if($counter==0){
            $check=$term->parent;
            $counter=1;
        }
        if($check==$term->parent)
        {
            $prod_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_".$term->term_id);
            echo $prod_meta['parent']; 
            $prod_meta['img'] = strstr($prod_meta['img'], '/wp-content');

            $sorted_products[$prod_meta['sort_order']] = array(
             'name' => $term->name,
             'link' => get_term_link($product),
             'term_id' => $term->term_id,
             'img' => $prod_meta['img']);
        }
        else{
            }
        } 
    ksort($sorted_products);
```

where ever the sort order for specific category is left empty then it is not shown. i want that default value for sort order should be 0.

Comment: @dingo_d kindly guide me here sir

Comment: @TeeDeJee kindly guide me here sir

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress taxonomy terms can only be sorted in ASC or DESC order. Currently, custom sort order is "out of the box".